# Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables whit uniform distribution, find $P\left[X\geq Y\right]$ and $P\left[X=Y\right]$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables with uniform distribution over 
$\left\{0,1,2, \dots, N\right\}$.

Find $P\left[X\geq Y\right]$ and $P\left[X=Y\right]$.

Following the definitions I've found that $\left[X\geq Y\right]=\left[X-Y\geq 0\right]=1-\left[X-Y< 0\right]$ but I'm stuck here, because the folowing member of the equality should be $1$ less the distribution of $X-Y$ evaluated in $0$?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion provided.

Comment: Do you assume that $X,Y$ are independent? Without some assumption like this, you don't have enough information to compute what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the observation. Indeed, they are independent.

Comment: How does $P(X\geq Y)$ compare to $P(Y\geq X)$? What is the sum and difference of these two probabilities? How can you simply compute $P(X=Y)$?

Comment: There are (N+1)^2 possible outcomes for (X,Y). How many of them correspond to X=Y? To X>Y? Thus...

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $X$ and $Y$ can only take finitely many values, and that they are independent:
\begin{align*}
P(X = Y) &= P(\{X = 0, Y = 0\} \cup \{X = 1, Y = 1\} \cup \dots \cup \{X = N, Y = N\})\\
&= P(X = 0, Y = 0) + P(X = 1, Y = 1) + \dots + P(X = N, Y = N) \\
&= P(X = 0) P(Y = 0) + P(X = 1) P(Y = 1) + \dots + P(X = N) P(Y = N)\\
&= \Big(\frac1{N+1}\Big)^2 + \Big(\frac1{N+1}\Big)^2 + \dots + \Big(\frac1{N+1}\Big)^2 \\
&= \frac{N+1}{(N+1)^2} \\
&= \frac1{N+1}.
\end{align*}

Or you count outcomes, as suggested by Did: There are $N+1$ outcomes where $X = Y$; and there are $(N+1)(N+1)$ outcomes in total. So $P(X = Y) = \frac{1}{N+1}.$

Comment: $P(X = Y) = \frac{N+1}{(N+1)^2}=\frac{1}{N+1}$

Comment: Ah sorry, you are right of course! Fixed it in the original answer...

Answer (score -1):

I believe that $P(X=Y)=0$, if $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables. For the continuous case, $X$ and $Y$ can take infinitely many values. From the results of Elias Strehle, we know that
$$
P(X=Y)=\lim\limits_{N \to \infty}\dfrac{1}{N+1}=0 \;.
$$

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables.

Comment: If you want to approximate the continuous uniform distribution, just taking the limit doesn't make much sense without scaling.